# Indefinite articles in front of number below 100

Tags: indefinite-article

Which number must I add "a"?

Do I start with "a"? (e.g. a ten people came to the event.)

Or do I start with "an"? (e.g. an eleven people came to the event.)

Comment: Is my edit helpful thanks? It wasnt very clear intially

Comment: @DialFrost 
It is OK. I now know this is wrong but I used to think that you would add "a/an" when the number gets bigger like 100. So I wanted to know when you start adding "a/an" between 10 to 99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need an articles for numbers!

The only exception is any number that starts with 1

> 100 -> one hundred -> a hundred

> 1000 -> one thousand -> a thousand

Comment: Thank you! It is clear.  I got confused because I saw "an eighty percent".

Comment: "An eighty percent" is wrong unless its "an eighty percent increase" as the "an" describes the "percent" @estudent

Comment: @estudent - maybe you saw 'an eighty percent _something_', such as 'an eighty percent increase'?

Comment: @DialForst When you talk about a score on a test. Don't you say "a score of an eighty"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I came across this line. "A score of a seventy-five is well below the average IQ in her age group."

Comment: @estudent - I would class that as an error, and remove the indefinite article 'a'.

Comment: Informally, in the UK, I do not know about elsewhere, people might say in conversation, 'I go an 80 in the test', but not in any kind of formal or academic writing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you. In an informal situation,  would you also say like that even if you received a lower mark? I.e., "I got a 5 or a 10"?

Comment: @estudent - the number is irrelevant. I got a zero, I got a 50, I got a hundred, I got an A, B, C, etc.

Comment: With letters the indefinite article is appropriate for the letter sound so an A, a B, a C, an F.